# How to maximize a floating div width when one div is removed or hidden?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two div columns sidebar(left) and page-content(right). I toggle removing and adding 'sidebar' using jquery but unable to maximize '#page-content' to take up the empty space when sidebar is removed.I tried removing 'margin-left:250px;' but the #page-content is going to the bottom. 
In short i want

Toggle before

| sidebar | page-content |

Toggle after

| page-content                |

but it happens like

| sidebar |
| page-content                |

Please help. Here is the css and jquery used. Thanx

**css**

```
#sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:185px;
    color:#333;
    padding:25px 25px;
}

#page-content {
    margin-left:250px;
    padding:25px 35px 25px 25px;
    color:#333;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a#side-toggle').click(function() {
  $('#sidebar').toggle(400);

 return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it should work actually.

Try to add a callback function to `.toggle()` where you animate/remove the margin from your content, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a#side-toggle').click(function() {
    $('#sidebar').toggle(400, function(){
        $('.page-content').animate({marginLeft: '0'}, 1000);
    });

    return false;
 });
});
```

working example:   http://jsbin.com/eqiyu/edit

updated version from Reigel:    [jsbin.com/eqiyu/2][2]

[2]: http:// jsbin.com/eqiyu/2

Comment: Thanks it works first time but toggling it overlaps.
what i used

  $('a#slick-toggle').bind('click', function(){
    $('#sidebar').toggle(400, function(){
      $('#page-content').animate({marginLeft: '0'}, 1000);
    });
  });

});

Comment: first time it works perfectly but after it became like this
Line 1 | sidebar |
Line2  | page-content                |

Comment: Thank you so much.It worked very well.I learned a lot from your replies.Thank you all for helping me. Iam really grateful to all your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#sidebar {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:185px;
    color:#333;
    padding:25px 25px;
}

#page-content {
    margin-left:250px;
    padding:25px 35px 25px 25px;
    color:#333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /**/
}

#page-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 250px;
    /**/
}
```

Assuming the left margin on #page-content is so it doesn't overlap #sidebar, after you run $("sidebar").toggle(), you need to set #page-content's margin to either 0 or 250px depending on the toggle's state.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#side-toggle").click(function() {
        $("#sidebar").toggle(400, function() {
            var m = ($("#page-content").css("margin-left") == 250 ? 0 : 250) + "px";
            $("#page-content").animate({ marginLeft : m }, 400);
        });
    });
});
```